# c++ sorting by primary followed by secondary criteria

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading

for a class project we are making a grep type program that runs multiple threads and we need to store the file name, and line number that a word is matched. the results need to be sorted first by filename, then by line numbers

So i have

```
namespace ultragrep
{
    class File {

    public:
        int lineNumber;
        std::string contents;
        std::string fileName;

        File(int ln, std::string lc, std::string fn) : lineNumber(ln), contents(lc), fileName(fn) {};
        File() {};
        ~File(){};

        string ln_toString() {
            return "[" + std::to_string(lineNumber) + "]";
        }

        string contents_toString() {
            return " \"" + contents + "\" ";
        }

    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const File& f) {
        return out << "[" << f.fileName << "]...";
    }

    //operator < so sort works 
    bool operator < (File& lhs, File& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.fileName < rhs.fileName;
    }
}
```

and when all my threads are done in my main() i have

```
sort(files.begin(), files.end());

for (ultragrep::File file : files)
{
    cout << file << file.ln_toString() << file.contents_toString()  << endl;
}
```

and this seemingly returns the results i am expecting but there is no guarantee that the line numbers are also sorted within' a grouping of results.

example results:

```
[file1.txt]...[1] "clock hello"
[file4.txt]...[1] "hello hello "
[file4.txt]...[2] "hello"
[file4.txt]...[3] "hello hello hello hello "
[file4.txt]...[5] "hello"
[file6.txt]...[3] "hello"
```

is there a snippet of code i could add into the < overload to account for a secondary sort param?

Comment: The reason std::string::compare exists is so you can do that kind of thing efficiently.  First save the result of std::string::compare.  If that result is zero, you need to also test the secondary criteria.  But either nonzero result from the first compare means the second isn't needed.  Something like `return (c=lhs.fileName.compare(rhs.fileName))<0 || c==0 && lhs.line<rhs.line`

Answer (score -2):

```
//operator < so sort works 
bool operator < (File& lhs, File& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.fileName == rhs.fileName)
    {
        return lhs.lineNumber < rhs.lineNumber;
    }
    return lhs.fileName < rhs.fileName;
}
```